# Quiero hacer un programa que elimine todos los enteros pares de una lista introducida por teclado

Tags: python, bucle-for

Me da error en mi segundo bucle for:

> if (l[x])%2==0: IndexError: list index out of range

```
rango = int(input("Numero de elementos de la lista: "))
l = []

for i in range(rango):
    l.append(int(input("Añadir elemento a la lista: ")))

print (f"La lista con numeros pares es {l}")    
    
for x in l:
    if x%2==0:
        l.remove(x)
        
print (f"La lista sin numeros pares es {l}")
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] ¿Intentaste depurar paso a paso tu código para saber qué sucede?

Comment: no es necesario que hagas esto `if (l[x])%2==0:` simplemente basta con esto `if (x%2==0:` ya que el for va sacando cada elemento de la lista y los almacena en la variable x, y en el ultimo print se te olvido poner la `f` antes de las comillas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in l:
    if (l[x])%2==0:
        l.remove(x)
```

`l` es una lista. Horrible nombre para una variable, pero en fin.

`x` es un elemento de la lista. Si la lista es `['A', 'B', 'C']` (uso letras para que sea más claro), entonces `x` puede ser `A, B o C`.

O sea, `x` no es un indice en la lista; `x` es un valor de la lista.

El código correcto sería:

```
for x in l:
    if x %2 == 0:
        l.remove(x)
```

Nota: Te falta la `f` en los `print`. La forma correcta es

```
print (f"La lista con numeros pares es {l}")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Acabo de empezar con python jajajaja

Comment: Pues simplemente lee en inglés: `for x in l`, usando nombres de variables decentes sería: `for numero in lista`, es decir "Para cada número en la lista"... si usas nombres de variables comprensibles, el propio código te dice lo que hace. Python es así de pytonudo. Por cierto, no se *debe* eliminar elementos de una lista según la estás iterando, pues podría inducir a problemas.